# GraphQL get all results for a collection

Tags: graphql, express-graphql

I am trying to get a list of all items in a collection with graphql, i am new to this and right now trying multiple things but nothing is working, below is what makes sense to me but as i said doesnt work to fetch all results in the collection, the mongo collection is called `userInterest`

```
    query {
    userInterest {
        id
    }
    }
```

Comment: That is probably not enough information to help you. How is this query resolved on the server?

Comment: im not sure, how do i find that ? Im using expressJS

Comment: Maybe check the documentation here: https://graphql.org/graphql-js/running-an-express-graphql-server/ . I am not very familiar with express-graphql, but there has to be a method somewhere which resolves the query (i.e. loads the necessary data from the database)